# Unit testing with Oracle

Tags: oracle, unit-testing, plsql

Does anyone have any frameworks/apps/methodologies for creating Unit tests with Oracle?. I'm using Oracle 11g.

I also have Team Foundation Server installed, where we do all our other development work with Visual Studio on a web app.

**Edit:**
I'm looking to run unit tests on Packages, Procedures and Functions within Oracle (PL/SQL)

Comment: What language/framework are you developing your app in?  Usually unit tests are done in the language/framework your app is written with.  Are you specifically looking to unit test stored procedures and such?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152441/unit-testing-for-pl-sql http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203376/unit-testing-framework-for-oracle-pl-sql

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a couple of options. Oracle SQL Developer has [a built-in test suite](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15846_01/doc.21/e15222/unit_testing.htm#RPTUG45000) but that's no use for people using other IDEs such as PL/SQL Developer, and also not helpful for CI purposes.

The best choice is [UTPLSQL](http://utplsql.org/), which was originally written by the renowned Steven Feuerstein.  This is pure PL/SQL.  It is pretty good and free open source software.

The really good news is that - after a long period of hibernation - UTPLSQL is back in active support. Version three is a complete re-write, with clever support for readable tests: it's a lot more like the JUnit and NUnit style of unit testing. Excitingly there are hooks for running UTPLSQL tests - including rendered output - in CI tools like TeamCity, Jenkins, etc. There is also a community of developers writing helpful extensions, such as [a SQL Developer plugin](https://github.com/utPLSQL/utPLSQL-SQLDeveloper).

There's a migration tool for v2 tests.

---

Author's note: I have completely re-written this answer to reflect the fact that UTPLSQL is now an active product again.