# What JUnit-style frameworks are available for unit testing PL/SQL in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, unit-testing, plsql

I'm looking to introduce automated unit testing to a large body of existing Oracle PL/SQL functions, procedures, and types. I would like to use an existing framework that is conceptually as close as possible to JUnit. Free-as-in-beer is required. Apache 2 or similar open source license is a plus. The framework must work in Oracle 10 and 11. Anything that requires changes to the code being tested isn't an option. Active development and strong community support are desired.

What frameworks are available that at least come close to this description?

Comment: Have you looked at the suggestions in this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152441/unit-testing-for-pl-sql ?

Comment: No, my searches didn't turn that up. I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1):

One option I have found is [PLUTO](http://code.google.com/p/pluto-test-framework/). I haven't tried it yet, but assuming it is currently functional, it still comes short on a few points:

- GPL licensed
- No activity for 9 months
- No sign of community support

Answer (score 1):

Why not try [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html)?  You already have Oracle, and this tool doesn't cost you any more.  I use Toad myself, but that is a (small) cost.

Check out this link to using it for [unit testing](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18464_01/doc.30/e17472/unit_testing.htm#BCGHEHFE)

Comment: That is an option. However, I would rather not be shackled to SQL Developer. We have some people using SQL Developer now and others using Toad. I use Eclipse as much as possible, personally. I would like a tool that works for all of us, from the command line, and ultimately as part of a Jenkins CI build as well. There is a command-line tool mentioned in your linked article, but I don't know yet how feature-rich it is or how much baggage it would carry.

Comment: well, its put out by Oracle, so any bugs are going to be hammered out (unlike many open source projects which get abandoned).  I cant attest to the command line tool, but I would give this serious consideration.

Answer (score 0):

See [Unit testing for PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152441/unit-testing-for-pl-sql)

Comment: That was linked in the question comments as well. The recommendations seemed to be utPLSQL, which is inactive as far as I can tell, and SQL Developer, which I commented on via tbone's answer. I take it this isn't a very active area.